# NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0702b9

Tags: android, android-resources

Выскочила такая ошибка:

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0702b9.

Это происходит на одном аппарате. На всех остальных все нормально. Может кто подсказать, где можно почитать информацию по данному вопросу? Или может кто сталкивался с подобным.
    Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Покажите, как вы эту строку устанавливаете.

Comment: Пишет, что отсутствует нужный ресурс, какая то иконка, строка и подобное. Видимо вы используете не собственные ресурсы приложения, а ресурсы из API Android и на какой то прошивке, собранной в самом центре Китая или отечественным ромоделом-умельцем этот ресурс был из прошивки выпилен.

Comment: На самом деле вообще не понятно, что произошло. Нашел строку с ресурсом, удалил(строка меняла внешний вид интерфейса), все пошло. Потом вернул строку обратно, все стало нормально.